# String .equals method not working (String object)

Tags: java, string, equals

I am trying to split a line of String text into an array, and perform an SQLite3 query on String elements that don't equal words such as "a", "to", or "on".

Here is the method I am using that splits a String into an array:

```
public static String[] extract(String string) {
    String[] splitArray = null;
    try {
        splitArray = string.split("\\s+");

    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return splitArray;
}
```

Next, using a for loop I am trying to run a queries on parts of the array that don't include the aforementioned words:

```
String garlic = "1 small garlic clove, finely grated on a microplane";
String[] queryArray = extract(garlic);
for (int i = 0; i < queryArray.length; i++ ) {
if (!queryArray[i].equals("a") || !queryArray[i].equals("to") {
   performQuery(queryArray[i]);
}
```

I have tried calling `.trim();` on the array element, but these `String` are still being queried despite seeming to be equivalent to the code.

The initial `String` has been copy pasted from a website - does that have any effect vs. just typing the `String` out? Copying and pasting from the website is necessary for my program so please give advice on how to work with that. If tried copying the a line from a webpage into a new `String` object, and then retyping the same line out, and I get the same result.

Please help!

Cheers.

Comment: You probably meant to use `&&` instead of `||` in the `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition `if (!queryArray[i].equals("a") || !queryArray[i].equals("to")` means that the `String` has to be different of `a` OR different of `to` so it'll be always true (`to` is different of `a`), you need to use `&&`

But you says that there is also `on`, to avoid a long condition, you can do :

```
String garlic = "1 small garlic clove, finely grated on a microplane";
String[] queryArray = extract(garlic);
List<String> toAvoid = Arrays.asList("a", "to", "on");
for (int i = 0; i < queryArray.length; i++ ) {
    if (!toAvoid.contains(queryArray[i])) {
        performQuery(queryArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, what a simple solution. Can't believe I missed that, I think that I was thinking  because it can't equal both of those things at once it must be OR and not AND. Makes sense now though when I think about it. I appreciate the extra bit of advice as well, thanks!

Comment: You could also use `HashSet` instead of  `List` but for collection of 3 elements it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

Every string will be not equal to at least one of `["a", "to"]`. what you want is an `&&` operator between your two conditions.

```
if (!queryArray[i].equals("a") && !queryArray[i].equals("to")) {
   performQuery(queryArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Or `!(queryArray[i].equals("a") ||queryArray[i].equals("to") )`.